# Using set builder notations with the laws of logical equivalences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am struggling with using set builder notations alongside the laws of logical equivalences - both prenciples i understand but when combined I do not. for example to show that,

(P−R) ∪ (Q−R) = (P ∪ Q)−R

I understand that it is

= (P ∩ R) ∪ (Q ∩ R)

= (P ∪ Q) ∩ R

= (P ∪ Q) − R

(i think)

but do I just add {x| } to each line?

thank for your time and patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set builder notation is a way to describe set by describing the criteria an element has to satisfy to be an element of the set. For example, consider

$$A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}| n\geq 3\}=\{3,4,5,...\}$$

This is "read" as: $A$ is the set of integers which are at least $3$.

In your example, $$(P−R) \cup (Q−R)=\{ x|( x\in P \text{ and } x\not\in R) \text{ or } ( x\in Q \text{ and } x\not\in R) \}$$

Now $$( x\in P \text{ and } x\not\in R) \text{ or } ( x\in Q \text{ and } x\not\in R) $$ is the same as saying $$(x\in P \text{ or } x\in Q) \text{ and } (x\not\in R)$$

Hopefully this should be enough for you to continue.